# Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I've just started to use Protractor. I created several page objects and everything is working fine till now. I log in to a page and I'm being redirected to the myaccount page.

On that page, I got the following error:
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.

My code is here:

```
var myaccount = function(){

//some function but everything is commented out
};
module.exports = new myaccount();
```

Here is my login test as well:

```
    this.loginSuccess = function(){
    userName.sendKeys(params.registration.email);
    password.sendKeys(params.registration.password);
    submitButton.click();
};
```

After the click, myaccount page appears but the protractor throws the mentioned error.

Could somebody help me with this?

Comment: Oh and one more thing. I'm familiar with java and I can return a new page object during the test. (e.g: using page factory) Can I do the same in protractor? Or is it necessary to return different page object? Thanks!

Comment: I also got the same error.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem? If so can you please post an answer and accept it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the answer from mcalthrop here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/610

Can use like

```
var newpage = new RegExp('welcome', 'i');
submitButton.click();
waitForUrlToChangeTo(newpage).then(function () {
        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Welcome!');
});
```

```
/**
 * @name waitForUrlToChangeTo
 * @description Wait until the URL changes to match a provided regex
 * @param {RegExp} urlRegex wait until the URL changes to match this regex
 * @returns {!webdriver.promise.Promise} Promise
 */
function waitForUrlToChangeTo(urlRegex) {
    var currentUrl;

    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function storeCurrentUrl(url) {
            currentUrl = url;
        }
    ).then(function waitForUrlToChangeTo() {
            return browser.wait(function waitForUrlToChangeTo() {
                return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function compareCurrentUrl(url) {
                    return urlRegex.test(url);
                });
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.angular is undefined` means you are trying to make protractor go to a page that is not angular