# Protractor "window.angular is undefined" error with PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, protractor

All of my tests run without issue in Chrome or Firefox, but when Protractor is used, I'm getting the following error message:

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/nexttick.js:41
  goog.global.setTimeout(function() { throw exception; }, 0);
                                      ^
Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"

Going to http://git.io/v4gX results in a 404 error.

I'm encountering this same error message whether using

```
$ webdriver-manager start      or
$ phantomjs --webdriver=9515
```

Using Protractor v3.0.0 and PhantomJS 2.1.1

I've seen similar queries for this issue:
 [Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34900470/error-while-waiting-for-protractor-to-sync-with-the-page-window-angular-is-und)

The stated answer is we're trying to make phantomJS go to a page that isn't Angular, but that is definitely not our situation, as the page is Angular.

["window.angular is undefined." when using protractor for automated testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938841/window-angular-is-undefined-when-using-protractor-for-automated-testing)

Here the supplied answer is use Protractor 3.0 and specify Jasmine2. Those are our currently supplied settings.

[Protractor running tests on PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058910/protractor-running-tests-on-phantomjs?rq=1)

States this issue was fixed in a prior Protractor release, but it appears to be back again.

I'm re-asking this question because the previous answers are now obsolete and irrelevant.